# Nuxt/TypeScript: Cannot access this - TS2339: Property 'XXX' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a problem using Nuxt.js with TypeScript. In my project I use dependencies like axios or nuxt-i18n. For this example I am using Axios. I configured it like in the [documentation](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage) for nuxt/axios

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios']
  axios: {},
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/axios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to use $axios in my Vuex store like this:

```
{
  actions: {
    async getIP ({ commit }) {
      const ip = await this.$axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
      commit('SET_IP', ip)
    }
  }
}
```

But now I get the error:

```
`TS2339: Property '$axios' does not exist on type '{ getIP(state: any, { commit }: { commit: any; }): Promise ; }'.`
```

**Edit:** The comments say, that using an arrow function should help. I tried it like this:

```
export const actions = {
  getIP: async ({commit}) => {
    const ip = await this.$axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
    ...
  }
};
```

but now the following error appears on "this."

```
TS7041: The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.
```

Comment: Use arrow function to define getIP function may solve your problem.

Comment: Simple functions are context based, and use 'this' keyword as your access internal atttibute (since this function aren't inside a class or some function). Arrow functions don't do this, and get the context of 'this' of your parents contexts.

Comment: @DanielFarina I edited my post, using an arrow function. but now there is another error. could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 6):

After adding axios plug `nuxt.config.js` inside the `plugins` folder add `axios-accessor.ts` with the following content :

```
import { Plugin } from '@nuxt/types'
import { initializeAxios } from '~/utils/api'

const accessor: Plugin = ({ $axios }) => {
  initializeAxios($axios)
}

export default accessor
```

then create a folder named `utils` and inside it add the file `api.ts` :

```
import { NuxtAxiosInstance } from '@nuxtjs/axios'

let $axios: NuxtAxiosInstance

export function initializeAxios(axiosInstance: NuxtAxiosInstance) {
  $axios = axiosInstance
}
   
export { $axios }
```

In your store you could import the `$axios` like :

```
import { $axios } from '~/utils/api'

...

{
  actions: {
    async getIP ({ commit }) {
      const ip = await $axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com') //use $axios without this
      commit('SET_IP', ip)
    }
  }
}
```

For more details check [this](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/store)

Comment: I find it strange this isn't referenced in the docs. The shown example with `this.$axios` does not work out of the box. Anyway, this is a working solution, thank you! Also don't forget to list the plugin in `nuxt.config.js` (`plugins: ['~/plugins/axios-accessor.ts'],`), so it will be initialized.

Comment: having the same issue with $nuxt... anyone else?